# Running python script periodically with crontab. Error

Tags: python, django, cron

I'm using crontab to run this python script every minute:

```
def cronSendEmail():
    print("Hello")
    return True
```

In the log file: `/var/log/syslog`

```
Jan  3 23:37:01 brahmh CRON[4627]: (me) CMD (/home/venv/bin/python /home/proj/manage.py crontab run b74d4d1f47748498b81b5bcf863684c3 >> /home/proj/file.log # django-cronjobs for proj
Jan  3 23:37:02 brahmh CRON[4626]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

These two statements are logged every minute. Why am I seeing 'no MTA installed, discarding output'? Also the program is not printing 'Hello' to the file.log as expected.

Note: This is a django project and I'm using django-crontab to create the crontab jobs.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog